# jquery change value of textbox by using a string

Tags: jquery

I am trying to implement and undo feature in my webpage. It is a table full of editable texboxes so coming up with an id was hard. I decide to make an id name based of the table inforamtion. Here is an id for example:

```
 HW3=:25626=:10000
```

HW3 is the header, 25626 is the id column for the row and 10000 references this table. For the undo feature i get the id by using

```
 $(this).attr('id);
```

and this funciton is called based on the event focus or click that is why 'this' works. I take the current value and add it to the end like

```
 $(this).attr('id)+":="+old_value;
```

This is done becuase the id name is seperated by "=:" so i can do two splits to get this data back in parts. Might not be best I understand.

The problem i am having is when I try to pull out the id and put it back as an element I get the error:

```
 Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #HW3=:25626=:10000
```

I am trying to do:

```
  var s = "#"+temp[0];
  var element = $(s);
```

temp[0] is = to HW3=:25626=:10000. It is the second line throwing this error.

IMPORTANT!!! The table that has the id that I am using is not created in the begining. JQuery calls a method that builds it after page loads. This method can not be access until after the table is created. I understand that you can not bind events to elements until after they load but I'm not sure if the is that same case since i will never try to undo on a textbox that is not present. After all it had to be present to be inserted into the Undo object already.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Your ID isn't going to work in a selector. You have to do something like this instead:

```
$(document.getElementById(temp[0]))
```

Comment: How do you come up with that? if `document.getElementById(temp[0])` will work then `$("#"+temp[0])` should too, no?

Comment: @mplungjan: Not if the attribute contains characters that will break the selector. `foo.bar` is a valid id, but it'll make the selector work improperly.

Comment: what characters are invalid for a selector because this does not work. But i also found out that even typing in the id by hand does not work so i think im using invalid characters or something.

Comment: ok i found a list of valid characters and  my = was not on it. So i changed those to -. Still not working. I did find that on my textbox when i change the value it does not change the value of the code. Still not getting this to work